# Tensorflow: InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'yy' with dtype int32

Tags: python, tensorflow

```
import tensorflow as tf
y_hat = tf.constant(36, name='y_hat')            # Define y_hat constant. Set to 36.
yy = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[])

loss = tf.Variable((yy - y_hat)**2, name='loss')  # Create a variable for the loss

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()    

with tf.Session() as session:
    session.run(tf.global_variables_initializer(), feed_dict = {yy: 39})
    print(session.run(loss, feed_dict={yy: 39}))
```

Being a total newbie in Tensorflow, I am having difficulties understanding how placeholders are managed in this framework.

If I run the code above for the first time, it returns 9 (correct value).
But if I run it again within the same jupyter session, I get the error below. It is as if global variables, in this case placeholders, are not getting cleanup though I am using "with" to close the session

Stack trace:

```
InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'yy' with dtype int32
     [[Node: yy = Placeholder[dtype=DT_INT32, shape=[], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]()]]
Caused by op 'yy', defined at:
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
```

Any idea what is happening and how to fix it ?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Add the line `tf.reset_default_graph()` right below `import tensorflow as tf`, so that your tensorflow graph will reset every time you run the code. Then you will not get this error.

By the way, you don't really need to specify `loss` as variable. You could just run

```
import tensorflow as tf
y_hat = tf.constant(36, name='y_hat')    
yy = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[])

loss = (yy - y_hat)**2  

with tf.Session() as session:
    print(session.run(loss, feed_dict={yy: 39}))
```

The above code prints 9.

Comment: Didnt complete my answer. Anyway, I wanted to use tf. Variable on purpose to see how it behaves. With your approach (which I used before), I didn't face any problem. So somehow they do behave differently.